# Twitter API not showing old tweets?

Tags: twitter

I have a problem with twitter API. I tweeted in the past (around 400) but recently I haven't tweeted anything. When I try to fetch tweets by me using the twitter api, there are no results. How can I retrieve the older tweets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twitter doesn't return tweets older than a week through search api. Take a look at the limitations section from the below link:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: There isn't any free solution, but you can retrieve tweets up to 2 years back using twitter partners such as data-sift. You can take a look at their web-site. http://datasift.com/

Comment: -1 That limit applies to the Twitter Search API, not the Twitter API.

Comment: But to retrieve older tweets you have to use Search API, or is there any other way to retrieve older tweets that I am not aware of?

Comment: is there a way to search by a particular hashtag to get tweets longer than 7 days old?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem as you, so after see that Twitter Web Search works I've started to implement my own solution, you can see on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets). It is implemented in Java, but it will make a post on my blog to explain how to do in other languages. I've downloaded tweets without any problems, my last test I parse more than 600k within 2014 from some specific users.

Comment: Could you share link to you blog with this post, please? I'd like to do it in Python.

Comment: Hello, I did it in python, take a look: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

Comment: Any chance there is an R implementation of this? Does it still work?

Comment: I ask because I tried your command line implementation from the Readme, copied/pasted exact, and it just yells at me to provide arguments.

Comment: Actually, I got your Java implementation working. The Python one just hates me for some reason.  Is there a way to modify this to instead of including just M/D/Y, get Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute:Second time stamps?

Comment: Hi @Jibril, it is possible, you can change the exporter.java and modifiy the date formatter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the REST API resource [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html) to retrieve the most recent 3200 tweets from any public timeline.

Comment: this is good to know, but not a solution if you're searching for all tweets with a certain hashtag

Comment: @Flion True, but that's a different question!

Comment: Is there a way to get older tweets with a certain search criteria? For example, any tweets mentioning a certain @user?

Comment: using GET statuses/user_timeline you can get tweets posted by user only.

Comment: @bittu you can get tweets posted by any regular user.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee is there a way to search twitters API for a specific hashtag for longer than the past 7 days?

Comment: @AVERAGE The answer to your question lies in the [Twitter API Reference Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in Twitter web search portal but not through their API. Bummer
https://twitter.com/search-home

Answer (score 1):

This elaborates on @bennett-mcelwee 's answer where getting up to 3200 most recent user tweets can be done in series of API calls.  Currently the max # of tweets you can get by a user in 1 request is 200, using the `GET statuses/user_timeline` API call. To get all tweets a user has posted on their timeline do the following:

STEP 1

Make a GET call to this endpoint passing parameter `count=200`.

STEP 2

From the returned data in step 1, get the ID of the last tweet

Make the same GET call but this time pass in parameter `max_id=` followed by the ID of last tweet returned form the first call, or `-1`. So for example `max_id=9987999`

STEP 3

Repeat step 2 until you don't get any new(older) data.

For my purpose I was able to do this in Ruby using https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Once a client object is instantiated, it's as simple as:

```
tweets = client.user_timeline('foobar', count: 200)
max_id = tweets.last.id - 1
tweets << client.user_timeline('foobar', count: 200, max_id: max_id)
```

From here you get idea and it's fairly trivial to write a loop until you've gotten all the tweets you can grab from the API.