# Extract Tweets of a particular user

Tags: r, sna

I am trying to get the tweets of a particular user on a specified period.

```
#Extract tweets from Donald Trump Timeline
dt_tweets = userTimeline("realDonaldTrump", n = 320, sinceID = "2016-11-09",
    maxID = "2019-01-28", includeRts = FALSE)
```

I got a list with 0 tweets. I didn't get any error.
I am looking for 320 tweets of the user on the particular time period.

Comment: Is there somewhere you saw that sinceID and maxID take dates? The examples I saw seem to use message IDs, not dates. Also, the twitter API doesn't make tweets available that far back. I would just leave out the `sinceID=` and `maxID=` parameters and see what's returned.

Comment: Thanks for responding back! I tried as per your idea but it extracted only 160 tweets. Is there any idea to extract tweets of the particular user on the specific time period?

Comment: Nope. The twitter API does not allow you to extract old tweets. That data is not freely available. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192155/twitter-api-not-showing-old-tweets